# Magento catalog image change on hover

Tags: css, image, magento, hover

On the catalog/category page I would like images change when hover. Like [clubmonaco.com](http://www.clubmonaco.com/family/index.jsp?categoryId=19749596&cp=12243590.12266330.19749596&ab=ln_women_features_dressshop) I know how to do it on html/css but no idea on magento. Any help? [image]

Comment: you will find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682097/magento-1-7-0-2-change-product-image-on-hover-in-catalog-page

Answer (score 0):

You could modify files in this directory:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product
for example (list/ and list.phtml)
```

or your template for example:

```
app/design/frontend/default/yourtemplate/template/directory with product files
```

CSS files you can find in:

```
skin/frontend/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also think, where the second image is stored. You can use "CSS-Sprites" for this case - a single image file, that contains both photos. The disadvantage is, that you have to customize every page, where magento shows product images.

Alternatively you have to define exact orders. First image is the front view, second image is always the back view.

The programming part is not really difficult. Look at

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

for the Catalog view. Path can vary, if you have a custom template. In the Magento backend there is a feature to show up the real path (system->configuration->development tools).

You can write your Javascript directly into the list.phtml. Magento also writes JS-code directly in the .phtml files. Of course it's not very pretty, but Magento is so complex; if other people work with the shop system, it will be easier to find.

Keep in mind, that the list.phtml contains two layouts: Grid and List View. Just if you do a change and wonder, why you can't see a change in the frontend ;-)