# Magento 1.7.0.2 change product image on hover in catalog page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to change images of products on mouse hover in the catalog page as you can see in this magento theme :

http://www.ethemeuk.com/dresscode/index.php/women-10/club-dresses.html

Thank you and i wait your reply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to show thumbnail image on mouse over & after mouse out show small image then go through :

```
app->design->frontend->default->your theme->template->catalog->product->list.pthml
```

in this 
Search this code:

```
 <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
```

in place of that put this code :-

```
 <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(135) ?>';" onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(135) ?>';" />
```

Now in admin assign different image for thumbnail and small image. thumbnail image will show when you mouse over on product image.

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer i was waiting for :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(217); ?>" width="147" height="217" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(217) ?>';" onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(217) ?>';" />

</a>
```

Note: I am constraining my pictures to be no more than 217 px wide - you will need to update this to reflect your design.

Comment: which is the file where i sould put this ? :)

Answer (score 0):

For anybody using the RWD theme that came about with 1.9, replace the  tag at line 59 with:

```
<img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                 src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(false)->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
                 onmouseover="this.src = '<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize($_imgSize) ?>';" 
                 onmouseout="this.src = '<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize($_imgSize) ?>';"
                 alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```